# How can I make package warnings and infos in luatex?

Tags: luatex

We can make errors with `tex.error()` in luatex like `\PackageError` in .sty or `\ClassError` in .cls, but how can I make warnings and infos in luatex like `\PackageWarning` or `\PackageInfo`?

Comment: Just `print()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LuaLaTeX provides three functions `module_info`/`module_warning`/`module_error` for such usecases under `luatexbase`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\directlua{
  luatexbase.module_info('mypackage', "For your information")
}
\directlua{
  luatexbase.module_warning('mypackage', "Please don't do this")
}
\directlua{
  luatexbase.module_error('mypackage', "That's not allowed")
}
\stop
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using `texio.write_nl()` and it works fine in vscode. But I don't know if it is the best way.

```
texio.write_nl("term and log","(file.name")
texio.write_nl("term and log","Package package_name Warning: Your warning")
texio.write_nl("term and log","\n)")
texio.write_nl("term and log","(file.name")
texio.write_nl("term and log","Package package_name Info: Your info")
texio.write_nl("term and log","\n)")
```

[image: how it is like in vscode]

Comment: yes that is the Lua interface to the TeX IO used by LaTeX Warning (term and log) and Info (log)